# Wordpress custom sort by meta key

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress query that I need to pull out the posts that have a custom meta key of "original-document". In short I need to have all of the posts with the meta key value in 1 column and the rest of the results in another column. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query posts:

```
query_posts('meta_key=original-document&orderby=meta_value');
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts